# setOnClickListener causes a crash of an APP

Tags: android, crash

Hello I have this very simple code I'm trying to run via Android Studio

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button random;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    random = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);

    random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            display.setText("I have changed");
        }
    });
```

I haven't really added very much, but whenever I use the setOnClickListener no matter what's inside of it crashes the app. I couldn't find a solution for this.

Thank you.

//edit: sorry. I added a wrong code, `random` is a button

Comment: can you post the LogCat?

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be your case but I had the same problem and it was caused by having these lines

```
mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // ...
}
});
```

before

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `setOnClickListener` method on the `random` object which by your code is currently `Null`.

So you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

I think you intended it to be `button` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I added a wrong code. It is already a "button" but still not working.

Comment: ok, so the next problem I see is the id of you display object: R.id.TextView. are you sure this is the id you gave it in the xml file activity_main? please try to switch it to display.

Comment: Yes that is the ID of a textview. I've changed it to "Tv" so it's less confusing, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: could you post your logcat? and your xml layout file?

Answer (score 0):

What is "random"? I think correctly will be:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        display.setText("I have changed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't this the same answer I gave?

Answer (score 0):

```
In your code  you are setting click listener on a button. Please make sure you get right id and right object to set listener. The button you want to set clcik listener on should have same id to the id you defined in you activity 

In Activity
Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

In XML
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: If you are still getting error Please post you error logcat so we can help you with right solution

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly***,check logcat by error level
***Secondly***,random is not initialized!!

You need

**1.Create button in activity_main.xml**

```
 For example, 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myCoolButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**2.Init that button in code**

Button myCoolButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myCoolButton);

**3.Attach listener to button**

```
myCoolButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    display.setText("I have changed");
}});
```

And it works! Hope that help you